# Display Date of last successful SSIS job in C# app

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am updating by code to include the entire .aspx source to give a better picture to those helping me on where to input code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection maindb = new SqlConnection(My_Connection);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "Select Statement";
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(str, maindb);

    maindb.Open();
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = sc;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "FirstName");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    maindb.Close();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "Different Select Statement";
    SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(str, maindb);

    maindb.Open();
    sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = sc;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "FirstName");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    maindb.Close();
}
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

}
```

I have a single step job that runs daily, which updates a few tables in SQL.

With my basic knowledge of C# I created an app that displays the data stored in that SQL table in a gridview. I would like to display on the app the last successful job run date, kind of a "Data Updated On" type of thing.

On other Stack Overflow question I found this code to display a row in SQL management studio with the last successful job.

```
DECLARE @job_id binary(16)
SELECT @job_id = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = N'YourJobName')
SELECT TOP 1
CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date))
+ ((run_time / 10000 * 3600) 
+ ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) 
+ (run_time % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964) AS run_datetime
, *
FROM
msdb..sysjobhistory sjh
WHERE
sjh.step_id = 0 
AND sjh.run_status = 1 
AND sjh.job_id = @job_id
ORDER BY
run_datetime DESC
```

The question I have is how do I go about displaying the Date in the actual app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = "Select Statement";
    //Replace 'YourJobName' with the name of your SQL Job!
    string sqlSelect = @"DECLARE @job_id binary(16)
    SELECT @job_id = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = N'YourJobName')
    SELECT TOP 1
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date))
    + ((run_time / 10000 * 3600) 
    + ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) 
    + (run_time % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964) AS run_datetime
    , *
    FROM
    msdb..sysjobhistory sjh
    WHERE
    sjh.step_id = 0 
    AND sjh.run_status = 1 
    AND sjh.job_id = @job_id
    ORDER BY
    run_datetime DESC";

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(My_Connection))
    {
        using (var sc = new SqlCommand(str, connection))
        {
            sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter() { SelectCommand = sc })
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "FirstName");
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            }
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect, connection))
        {
            var table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][0]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the code you mentioned into a "protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" but I feel that might not be the best way or the way you designed your statement.

Comment: You need to add a label named 'Label1' to your page. Also I improved your page load by introducing using statements, you'll want to do something similar for the button click.

Comment: After watching C# training videos I can make sense of the code you posted. Thank you very much. The only issue that I have with it though is on the actually assigning Label1.text to the table rows[0][0] which I take gets the first column in the table. The error message I get is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" I tried adding ToString to the end of things but no luck. I tried google but I haven't got a concrete answer that solves this issue for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I found it! This is what I had to do to get it to display: Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][0]); Thank you so much for sending me off on the right direction AlexMill.

Comment: I edited that solution in case others have the same problem.